# deselect mouse selection in emacs when moving cursor with arrow keys

Tags: emacs, textselection

Since the last update my emacs exhibits the following behviour: I select some text by dragging the mouse over it. Then I move the cursor with the arrow keys and the selected region gets modified as if I was holding shift. I find this somewhat annoying, because I sometimes accidentally select a character when I click somewhere. When I then move the cursor with the arrow keys, start typing and a region of text is deleted. I would like emacs to de-select the region when I use the arrow keys, just like it does when I selected with the shift-arrow key method. Is there a setting that lets me change this? I'm using GNU Emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior in Emacs-23.4 (don't have 23.3 at hand), neither when enabling cua-mode nor delete-selection-mode.  Do you see this behavior with `emacs -Q`?  If not, then try to figure out which part of your `.emacs` triggers the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in Emacs 23.3.1 (debian package) either.

Comment: Thanks. I had '(pc-selection-mode t nil (pc-select)) in my custom variables. No idea what it's for or how it got there, but removing it fixes the problem.